# split array on two arrays of all possible forms including repetitions order from first to second set but do not repeat the elements

Tags: python, arrays, split

I am looking for some solution and only meet responses from arrays divided into two based on the sum of the elements of the resulting arrays or the size of them to be equal or different. But nothing seems enough to help me.

Let's say I have an array as below:

```
array = [1,2,3]
```

I would like to find all ways to separate the elements of this array into two new arrays, regardless of the size of them are equal or different, that is:

```
[1] -- [2,3]
[2] -- [1.3]
[3] -- [1,2]
[2,3] -- [1]
[1,3] -- [2]
[1,2] -- [3]
```

I try to do this in Python and as I said I did not find a way to do this, although I know  `itertools` and `powerset`.
In fact I would like to print the output in a file having each pair of arrays side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from itertools import combinations

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

for i in range(1, len(array) + 1):
    lst = deepcopy(array)
    nlst1 = list(combinations(lst, i))
    nlst1 = [list(i) for i in nlst1]
    nlst2 = []
    for j in nlst1:
        lst = deepcopy(array)
        for k in j:
            lst.remove(k)
        nlst2.append(lst)

    for i in range(len(nlst1)):
        print(nlst1[i], nlst2[i])
```

Comment: Curious how you use this to get "all possible forms" especially given that you destroy the input list?

Comment: @CoderTang I see that requesting the impression at the end of the file as you did I can get the six ways, but this would not be very practical if my original array contains thousands of elements, even though I'm trying to adapt your code.

Comment: @CoderTang, I now get `IndexError: pop index out of range`.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm I updated it a bit. not sure if that helps

Comment: I also get it `IndexError: pop index out of range` , but I've learned two important things with @mark, great code.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm forgot to add a bit of code

Comment: @CoderTang I imagined having understood how to manipulate `[i, I-1] ` to print all possible ways but I can not do this when  `array = [1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, 12,13] ` for example, could you help me?

Comment: I modified  `[i, I-1] ` for  `[i, i, i] `  tested test and I presume I understood my misconception.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm I tried to do it with my old code, but that didn't work. So I did some more research and came up with a better one that CAN print out every possible combo! (See edits) It takes 1.5 seconds though.